# Shrink/filter view to only include matched lines

Tags: logging, terminal, iterm2, iterm

Using iterm2, is there a way to search for matching lines, and only include those lines in the output?

Right now if I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> - it will highlight matching text in yellow, but I am looking to filter out all lines that don't have matching text, is there a way to do this with a terminal application?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this documentation:
http://www.ifdattic.com/iterm-shortcut-keys

> Custom shortcuts keys
>
> You can change global shortcut keys from profile preferences Keys tab. One shortcut key I find useful is deleting the last word. It uses the ⌘←Delete as keyboard shortcut and sends the 0x1B 0x08 hex code (action).

Also see the folowing documentations:

https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html
https://gist.github.com/squarism/ae3613daf5c01a98ba3a